# How to make the audio track of a video fade in IOS

Tags: ios, audio, video, avfoundation

I am using AVMutableComposition & AVAssetExportSession and stuff to merge a music with a video *(the output is a mp4)*.

The whole thing worked fine, but when I tried to add fading effects using audio mix, the export would fail

Here's the code fragment for adding fading effect if it matters

```
AVMutableAudioMix* exportAudioMix = nil;
if(CMTimeCompare(videoAsset.duration, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(2, 25)) == 1) {
    exportAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *mixParam 
        = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:compositionAudioTrack];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        CMTime t = CMTimeMake(i * 5 , 25);
        [mixParam setVolume:0.2 * i atTime:t];
        [mixParam setVolume:0.2 * (5 - i) atTime:CMTimeAdd(videoAsset.duration, t)];
    }
    exportAudioMix.inputParameters = @[mixParam];
}
_assetExport.audioMix = exportAudioMix;//export won't fail if I remove this line
```

I tried to use setVolumeRamp... but it didn't work (Can't export) so I changed to setVolume which behaved the same. So I believe the problem shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured the problem after some struggle. My answer is here incase anyone else encounters this error (though it seems that this problem is just caused by a dumb mistake).

There's no problem on how I set the audio mix. The problem is that I initialized the export session with **passthrough** preset, which will take the input *as is* and would fail if there's an audio mix which modifies the audio track.

I changed the preset to *AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality* and everything worked well.